# Как или можно ли вообще из класса обратиться к объекту другого класса не создавая экземпляр этого класса директивой new внутри этого класса?

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

У меня есть class DatabaseConnection для подключения к базе данных.

```
class DatabaseConnection {

private $host = 'localhost';
private $databaseName = 'grossbux';
private $userName = 'root';
private $password = '';

public $dsn, $opt, $pdo;

function __construct()
{

  $this->dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->databaseName";
  $this->opt = [  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, ];

  try {
    $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn , $this->userName, $this->password, $this->opt);
  }

  catch(PDOException $e) {
    include 'php/stubs/db_conn_error.php';
  }

}
```

И каждый раз когда мне нужно отправить запрос в базу данных из другого класса, мне приходиться в самом начале этого другого класса создавать новый экземпляр класса DatabaseConnection.

```
$connect = new DatabaseConnection();
```

И уже только потом отправлять запрос в базу данных.

```
$result = $connect->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM...");
```

Можно ли обойти эти заморочки и получить возможность сразу писать запросы без объявления нового экземпляра класса DatabaseConnection или объявив его только один раз где нибудь вне классов?

P.S Новичок в ООП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать паттерн синглетон. То есть создаем внутри DatabaseConnection статический атрибут $instance как ссылку на экземпляр текущего класса и добавляем геттер на этот атрибут, который проверяет, не пустой ли он, если не пустой, то возвращает его, нет - создает новый объект DatabaseConnection  и возращает.

```
    class DatabaseConnection {

    private static $instance = null;

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $databaseName = 'grossbux';
    private $userName = 'root';
    private $password = '';

    public $dsn, $opt, $pdo;

    function __construct()
    {

      $this->dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->databaseName";
      $this->opt = [  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, ];

      try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn , $this->userName, $this->password, $this->opt);
      }

      catch(PDOException $e) {
        include 'php/stubs/db_conn_error.php';
      }
   }

      public static function getInstance() {
        return 
            self::$instance===null
                ? self::$instance = new self() 
                : self::$instance;
      }

    }
```

где-то в другом месте программы

```
$conn = DatabaseConnection::getInstance();
```

в этом случае экземпляр класса DatabaseConnection будет всегда только один.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей. Благодаря вам узнал о существовании паттернов. В вашем ответе были непонятные для меня слова (паттерн, сингелтон, геттер). Но я во всём разобрался, внёс в свой код добавленные вами правки и написал на основе полученных знаний вот такую функцию: function get($query) {
  $result = DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->pdo->query($query);
  return $result;
}

Comment: Теперь я могу просто вызвать её в любом месте программы и получить то, что мне нужно.  $result = get($query);